# Removing some lines in table

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&
\begin{sideways}ABCD\end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}EFGH\end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}IJKL\end{sideways} \\ \hline
AA & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
BB & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
CC & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
DD & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tmp}
\label{tab:tmp}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

How can I remove lines like in images below?

[image]

Also, how can I raise the first horizontal line a little up?
The final result should be:

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm afraid four different measures are neccessary:

1. Remove the vertical line with `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}`.
2. Remove the horizontal line (segment) with `\cline{2-4}`.
3. Add a bit of space to the longest label on the top.
4. If you don't want the "inner" vertical lines for most of the table, I'd add them specifically for the head.

Result:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|ccc|}
  \cline{2-4}
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{sideways}ABCD\hspace*{1mm}\end{sideways}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{sideways}EFGH\end{sideways}} &
  \begin{sideways}IJKL\end{sideways} \\ \hline
  AA & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  BB & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  CC & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  DD & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: output example]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using `tabularray`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec      = {*{4}{c}},
    vline{1}     = {2-4}{0.9pt},
    vline{2,5}   = 0.9pt,
    vline{3-4}   = {1}{0.9pt},
    hline{1}     = {2-5}{0.9pt},
    hline{2,5}   = 0.9pt,
    cell{1}{2-4} = {cmd={\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}}}
}
       & ABCD
       & EFGH 
       & IJKL  \\ 
    AA & 2 & 3 & 4  \\ 
    BB & 2 & 3 & 4  \\ 
    CC & 2 & 3 & 4  \\ 
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For those that need help figuring this out: `hline{1}` refers to the first horizontal line in the  table. `= {2-5}{0.9pt}` means "make this horizontal line span from the second vertical line to the fifth vertical line". `hline{2,5}` refers to the second and fifth lines in the tables.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `\multicolumn` and `\cline` to get the desired output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|ccc|}
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{sideways}ABCD\end{sideways}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{sideways}EFGH\end{sideways}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{sideways}IJKL\end{sideways}} \\ \hline
AA & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
BB & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
CC & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
DD & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tmp}
\label{tab:tmp}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In my opinion you can also omit the vertical lines in the header altogether, and also the border on top, left and right, giving

```
\begin{tabular}{c|ccc}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\begin{sideways}ABCD\end{sideways}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{sideways}EFGH\end{sideways}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{sideways}IJKL\end{sideways}} \\ \hline
AA & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
BB & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
CC & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
DD & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 4):

This remove also the vertical lines among numbers:

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccc|}
  \cline{2-4}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{}&
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{
    \begin{sideways}ABCD\hspace*{1mm}\end{sideways}}&
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{
    \begin{sideways}EFGH\hspace*{1mm}\end{sideways}}&  
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{
    \begin{sideways}IJKL\hspace*{1mm}\end{sideways}}\\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{AA} & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{BB} & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{CC} & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{DD} & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Or with `tabularx` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{3.5cm}{|X|XXX|}
  \cline{2-4}
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&
  \begin{sideways}ABCD\hspace*{1mm}\end{sideways}&
  \begin{sideways}EFGH~\end{sideways}&
  \begin{sideways}IJKL\end{sideways} \\
\hline
AA\newline BB\newline CC\newline DD 
& 2\newline2\newline2\newline2 
& 3\newline3\newline3\newline4 
& 4\newline4\newline4\newline4\\  
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

But maybe better with `tabulary`, and only `booktabs`horizontal lines:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabulary}{3cm}{LCCCC}
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-4}&
\rotatebox{90}{ABCD}&
\rotatebox{90}{EFGH}&
\rotatebox{90}{IJKL} 
\\\midrule
AA\par BB\par CC\par DD &
 2\par 2\par 2\par 2 &
 3\par 3\par 3\par 4 &
 4\par 4\par 4\par 4
\\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. In that environment, you have a key `hvlines` which draws all the rules excepted in the blocks (specified by `\Block` and in the empty corners (specified by the key `corners`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines,corners=NW] % NW = north-west
\RowStyle{\rotate}
       & ABCD \;
       & EFGH 
       & IJKL  \\ 
\Block{3-1}{}
    AA & \Block{3-3}{}
         2 & 3 & 4  \\ 
    BB & 2 & 3 & 4  \\ 
    CC & 2 & 3 & 4  \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]